# XStream doesn't support custom converter cross-delegation?

Tags: java, xstream

It appears to me that the Java XStream library does not support cross-delegation.  Am I correct in this belief?

So, I can explain what I mean, consider the following example:

```
<node-type-x>
  <node-type-y>
     <a/>
     <b/>
  </node-type-y>
<node-type-y>
  <c/>
  <d/>
```

Let's say we have a converter for "node-type-x" nodes and another converter for "node-type-y" nodes.  The functionality I would **like** to see in XStream would be sometype of **delegate()** method which I could call within the node-type-x converter that would identify nested node-type-y nodes and delegate unmarshalling to the converter for such nodes and return the result so that the node-type-x converter can process the result as needed.  As it stands, XStream seems to require that the converter for "node-type-x" handle processing of all children of such nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple ways to do this:

1. [Register your node-type-y converter](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#registerConverter%28com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter%29) with the XStream instance, and inside your node-type-x converter, call [marshallingContext.convertAnother(object)](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/MarshallingContext.html#convertAnother%28java.lang.Object%29).
2. Don't register your converter with the XStream instance, and inside your node-type-x converter, call [marshallingContext.convertAnother(object, converter)](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/MarshallingContext.html#convertAnother%28java.lang.Object,%20com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter%29), passing it the converter you'd like to use for the "y" that you passed it.

Comment: Yes, I understand now that convertAnother() is definitely the key here.  My original expectation was that convertAnother() should return the result from the conversion so that the parent can reassemble results from recursive call(s), but I understand now that this reassembly is achieved through the shared writer.  Not sure, if that is how I would have designed it myself but hey ... now I can do what I need!  Thanks :-)